# libgit2 how to do a commit of all files added_by_path

Tags: libgit2

I want to imitate this behaviour in `libgit`:

```
create files: touch {1..100}
git add .
git commit -a -e
```

For every file I create, I do the following:

```
do {
    git_index_read()
    git_index_add_bypath()
    git_index_write()
    git_commit_create() <--want this to be delayed after all files are created.
} while (0)
```

The above ops, the files get added and are shown in git log output.

What I would like to achieve:

```
do {
    git_index_read()
    git_index_add_bypath()
    git_index_write()

} while (0)
git_commit_create() <--want this to be delayed after all files are created.
```

If I delay git_commit_create till end of all creates, none of the files get added in the commit. But `git status -s` does show these staged files.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is?  It sounds like you have the answer - you need to `git_index_add_bypath` every item before you do a `git_commit_create`...

Comment: If I call git_commit_create after each git_index_add_bypath, the commits are good. What I want is to do a single commit for all creates (git_index_add_bypath). After the commit, the git show does not contain these files.

Comment: Then posting your actual code would be helpful, because you've outlined a general strategy that should do what you're asking.  `git_commit_create` builds a commit from the index.  If you've added those files to the index, they should be included.

Comment: I think the problem was missed git_free_tree () calls. I am using libgit2 as a versioning tool for a distributedfs - glusterfs (www.gluster.org). Will post the code review links soon.